# how to split list in chunk of list item in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

```
val listParentBarEntry : ArrayList<BarEntry>? = content["parentBarChartData"]
val listChildBarEntry : ArrayList<BarEntry>? = content["childBarChartData"]
```

this is my list item  both size is 24 i want to split into 4 split.
1st size should index 0 to 5
2nd size should index 7 to 12
3rd size should index 13 to 17
4th size should index 18 o 23

i am trying with groupBy but its not working please help me how to split list into 4 list with same type ArrayList.

Comment: Why not `subList` https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/sub-list.html

Comment: its type is not accepting could you please help me how to make it sublist with same type

Comment: You can use multiple of 4 and add increment of 1  into each multiple, so that way you will get 5,10,14,19,24 as your list sizes.

Comment: Seems like a design problem of whatever function you are passing these to that it specifically needs ArrayList instead of a generic List. Not to say there’s never a reason that needed but it should be rare.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `chucked` function to split a given collection into a list of lists where the size of inner list can be any chosen number.

```kotlin
val array = arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
println(array.chunked(6)) // [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

If the size of array is not divisible by 6, the last inner list will have the remaining (size % 6) elements.

This will give you a `List<List<Int>>`. If you really want it to be `ArrayList<ArrayList<Int>>` you can convert it like this:

```kotlin
array.chunked(6).map { it.toCollection(ArrayList()) }.toCollection(ArrayList())
```

Comment: But i need chunk of list  ArrayList<BarEntry> in this type

Comment: You don't want `ArrayList<ArrayList<BarEntry>>`? Can you please specify what return type do you want?

Comment: ArrayList<BarEntry> this should be my return type for each chunk list

Comment: And you want 4 such lists?

Comment: yes i want 4 list

Comment: You can get the new lists using the indices of the chucked list. Eg. `val list1 = chunckedList[0]`, `val list2 = chunckedList[1]` etc. Or you can also use list destructing for this.